# How to fix child view going over their parents bounds in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView and it has a background with rounded corners. The problem is that the ViewHolders inside the RecyclerView go over the bounds of the parent, although the clipChildren property is set to true.

How can this be fixed?

see image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

This piece of code solved it:

```
   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    fun clipViews(){
        myRecyclerView.clipToOutline = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need thes lines in first and last item so check in the adapter if the position is equal 0 and remove these lines

Comment: The problem is not only in the first and last items. The lines belong to the item and every item's content goes over the bounds of the parent recycler view when I scroll.